# a cure for gray hair is on the way?

Tags: medications, hair, treatment-options

I saw this [news article](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-4718576/No-dye-Cancer-patients-gray-hair-darkened-immune-drugs.html) (here is the [article](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamadermatology/article-abstract/2642914) about it in a medical journal) and began to wonder if the cure for gray hair is on the way. Those immunotherapy drugs can restore hair color only in people with cancer?, And what about the safety? It is dangerous to healthy people more than to cancer patients?.
The scientists now need to investigate the process behind the repigmentation of white hairs in those cases and develop a whole new drug for this?, or simply look for a way to make the existing drugs safer for treatments for white hairs?.

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE.  I am sorry but I am lost.  What is your question?  Are you asking if a cure is on its way or are you asking if the possible cure is safe? Or yet another possible question here is whether more research is required.  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I made several questions in one thread cause this case of those cancer drugs restoring color to white hair in those 14 people is raising a lot of questions.

Comment: Please visit the [help] and learn how this site works. @ChrisRogers is right that your question is unclear and too broad.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't read the article, only the abstract, but what it's saying is that, for people with grey or white hair, darkening of hair color is an indication that anti–PD-1/anti–PD-L1 treatment for lung cancer is working.  This is almost entirely unrelated to reversing age-related hair depigmentation.

(As a side note, I consider the Daily Mail to be comparable to [The Onion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Onion) when it comes to accuracy in medical reporting.)

Comment: what do you mean by "unrelated to reversing age-related hair depigmentation"? their white hairs where "age-related" and not from the cancer. and this isn't the first time a drug-related hair repigmentation is observed, it happened in other patients in other types of cancer or even without cancer at all and in fact i made another similar question just with another case that had nothing to do with cancer: https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/17124/hair-repigmentation-and-growth-from-secukinumab