# hair repigmentation and growth from secukinumab

Tags: medications, hair, hairloss

I saw this study([link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6031562/)) about a patient who received a drug called secukinumab and experienced hair re-pigmentation from white to black and hair re-growth and as you can see the results are pretty amazing. It was noted in the study that the results had nothing to do with the patient's psoriasis and said that it happened cause the drug inhibits the Interleukin 17 cytokine which affects hair graying.
So what does this study actually means? that secukinumab(with or without combination with other drugs) can be a potential cure for gray hair and hair loss?.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the study you're referring to?

Comment: the link was in the word "study" but now i put the link in the word "link" after the word "study". can you see it?

Comment: My apologies. I didn't notice it because the links here are very minimally highlighted.